# Live JavaScript translation blinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation

I have made a JavaScript translation of some text that occurs live rather than on server side, but it blinks when it replaces and thus is not user friendly. Is there anything I could do about it? I made

### **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMGLX/7/)**

and here is the summary of the code:

```
// bind the animation so I can catch a node inserted and then

if(event.animationName == "nodeInserted")
{
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('translate'))
    {
        $(event.target).text(Translate($(event.target).attr('translate')));
    }
}

// where function Translate() replaces the text
```

However it blinks when it replaces and I am out of ideas how this can be more eye friendly. I hope the example is simplistic enough to picture my problem.

Comment: A first idea of an answer could be to not replace the text as such, but write the translation into another element, and then substitute the "original text" element with the "translated text" one. I can't see anything wrong with your fiddle...but I can't see anything happening neither actually. What is it supposed to do ?

Comment: @Bartdude if you run it first time it lags a bit and you might not see what's wrong. But try clicking `Run` again, you will see the effect of text being replaced for a split second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, I can give few remarks. First, your animation is way to short (`0.001s`) which probably could be a reason why it blinks (animation happens too fast).

Also, your fade starts at `50%`, instead of `0%`.

Maybe I am wrong about all this, and I did not understand your question, but I have provided and edited fiddle so you can see for yourself what am I referring to. It is nice fading in this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/TMGLX/9/

Comment: The idea of the animation is to trigger the animation effect so I can see that the node has been added to the page. This is the best way to handle capturing nodes' insertion. On the other hand, the way you handled the issue looks neat and I will definitely take a deeper look. The `50%` itself was just taken from the example I found and I admit I didn't care to look at what exactly it does.

Comment: Well if you do not really need animation you can try and animate opacity from .99 to .1. It should make no visible difference but it would trigger the effect.

Comment: Well, I tried it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TMGLX/11/ but it doesn't seem to be any different from the original example. Or maybe I  misunderstood what you said. However, http://jsfiddle.net/TMGLX/9/ is so far the best attempt I have seen for this issue. Looks pretty smooth :)

Comment: By the way, originally the animation was `clip` but was changed to opacity because IE wasn't able to handle it until a certain version or at all (forgot which was the case, but doesn't matter).

Comment: At the end we decided to go with the server-side translations.

Comment: Well, it is the most logical thing to do :)